# How to import route collection in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to load yaml file with routes in symfony2. How to do that and where to add it to the existing routes?

This is my extra_routes.yml file:

```
_hello:
    pattern: /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello }
    requirements:
        name: ".+"

_hello2:
    pattern: /hello2/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello2 }
    requirements:
        name: ".+"
```

1. First, I need to load that file. So do i do that using yaml component? like this (i have to do this in php and not using import)?:

   $loader = new Yaml\Yaml::parse(**DIR**.'/../Resources/config/routing_extra.yml');
2. How do i import that into RouteCollection and where do I add that to existing routes?

Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to include it via `resource`:

```
extra:
    resource: '@YourModuleBundle/Resources/config/routing/extra_routes.xml'
    prefix: /custom_prefix
```

Comment: as i mentioned i need to do it in php

Comment: sry, overread it  - did you try http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/symfony2-dynamically-add-routes/ ?